# How can I change my icon color without filling inside?

Tags: android, vector, colors, icons

I'm trying to get my icon looking like this: [image]

However, it looks like: [image]

This is my code:

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        style="@style/FAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_border_24"/>

<style name="FAB" parent="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/FABShape</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/yellow</item>
</style>

<style name="FABShape" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerSize">10%</item>
</style>
```

This is the vector for the heart shape (from Google):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M16.5,3c-1.74,0 -3.41,0.81 -4.5,2.09C10.91,3.81 9.24,3 7.5,3 4.42,3 2,5.42 2,8.5c0,3.78 3.4,6.86 8.55,11.54L12,21.35l1.45,-1.32C18.6,15.36 22,12.28 22,8.5 22,5.42 19.58,3 16.5,3zM12.1,18.55l-0.1,0.1 -0.1,-0.1C7.14,14.24 4,11.39 4,8.5 4,6.5 5.5,5 7.5,5c1.54,0 3.04,0.99 3.57,2.36h1.87C13.46,5.99 14.96,5 16.5,5c2,0 3.5,1.5 3.5,3.5 0,2.89 -3.14,5.74 -7.9,10.05z"/>
</vector>
```

I'm expecting the vector to be an empty heart shape. But when I apply a tint color to it, it's coloring it inside. Is there a way I can get the tint color to only apply to the outside of the heart shape?

Answer (score 0):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M16.5,3c-1.74,0 -3.41,0.81 -4.5,2.09C10.91,3.81 9.24,3 7.5,3 4.42,3 2,5.42 2,8.5c0,3.78 3.4,6.86 8.55,11.54L12,21.35l1.45,-1.32C18.6,15.36 22,12.28 22,8.5 22,5.42 19.58,3 16.5,3zM12.1,18.55l-0.1,0.1 -0.1,-0.1C7.14,14.24 4,11.39 4,8.5 4,6.5 5.5,5 7.5,5c1.54,0 3.04,0.99 3.57,2.36h1.87C13.46,5.99 14.96,5 16.5,5c2,0 3.5,1.5 3.5,3.5 0,2.89 -3.14,5.74 -7.9,10.05z"/>
  <group
    android:scaleX="0.95"
    android:scaleY="0.95"
  >
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/black"
      android:pathData="M16.5,3c-1.74,0 -3.41,0.81 -4.5,2.09C10.91,3.81 9.24,3 7.5,3 4.42,3 2,5.42 2,8.5c0,3.78 3.4,6.86 8.55,11.54L12,21.35l1.45,-1.32C18.6,15.36 22,12.28 22,8.5 22,5.42 19.58,3 16.5,3zM12.1,18.55l-0.1,0.1 -0.1,-0.1C7.14,14.24 4,11.39 4,8.5 4,6.5 5.5,5 7.5,5c1.54,0 3.04,0.99 3.57,2.36h1.87C13.46,5.99 14.96,5 16.5,5c2,0 3.5,1.5 3.5,3.5 0,2.89 -3.14,5.74 -7.9,10.05z"/>
  </group>

</vector>
```

You could use the same path that creates the heart but scale it down slightly. If you  color it the same as the background it will look like an outline of a heart instead of a whole heart.